# How to call a method on MainWindows from another Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, methods, non-static

I have MainWindow.xaml and another Page.xaml in same namespace

On MainWindow are textblock and frame.

Frame on MainWindow showing Page.xaml and on that Page is one Button.

I want Call non-static method in MainWindow with that Button, but i dont know how :(

For example:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    namespace wpfapp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            openframe();
        }

        private void openframe()
        {
            frame1.Source = new Uri("testapge.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        }
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            textblock1.Text = "This text is showed on MainWindow if i click to the Button";
        }    
    }
}
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
    namespace wpfapp
{
    public partial class Page : Page
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow trytocallit = new MainWindow();
            trytocallit.MyMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

This of course doesnt work. Thank for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry for late reply, I have one simple resolution.

- In Page.xaml create public string variable.
- If you click to the button on the page, variable gets the some value.
- Create new background theard on MainWindow and there runs an endless loop while (true) {..}
- The cycle control of the value public string variable again and again... with Thread.Sleep(10);
- If it finds a value that does something in MainWindow

It works too and simply for me :)

Answer (score 3):

As alternative and fast solution, you can use following code

Usage:

```
   MainWindow mainWindow = GetMainWindow();
```

Method:

```
    public static MainWindow GetMainWindow() 
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow=null;

        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            Type type = typeof(MainWindow);
            if (window != null && window.DependencyObjectType.Name == type.Name)
            {
                 mainWindow = (MainWindow)window;
                if (mainWindow != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        return mainWindow;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i am try it, but i have a problem with it: The name 'ParentFinder' does not exist in the current context .. i try change it for something, for example MainWindow, now program can start, but button1 dont working, sorry this, you can try show me whole and functional code? I would like to understand

Comment: Ah sorry buddy, Just u should put the above method into any class to call it. For me it was ParentFinder.cs. So I have edited again, please have a look.

Comment: okay, but what now?  i try do some changes, it not working :(

Comment: Now its going without errors, its great, but how can i change texblock value with it? i am try it, but i dont know

Comment: Please modify the  method "public void MyMethod()"  . It can take string argument   like     public void MyMethod(string text).   Normally you should bind the Text property of the Textblock and update via properties.

Comment: Okay, i edited MyMethod() to MyMethod(string text) in MainWindows.xaml, now now it wants give some arguments to         `private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow trytocallit = new MainWindow();
            trytocallit.MyMethod();          
        }`
in Page.xaml, but what?

Comment: In your page or mainwindow, please create a string property field ,  before clicking the button , update  this string field  and use as argument in  MyMethod(string text).

Comment: and sorry, i don't understand it so much, but i try to learn it, i started with C# recently

Comment: Make a string field in page class .  like :  string TextTest = "test" ;  and update this field  before button click to like   TextTest = "abc" ;  and  use it  in trytocallit.MyMethod(TextTest ) ;

Answer (score 2):

You can do a couple of different things. You can implement something like [Muds' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29120567/2607840), which is similar to the [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Another alternative is to use [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) to give your `Page` class an instance of `MainWindow` when it is created.

```
public class Page : Page
{
  private MainWindow MainWindow;

  public Page(MainWindow mainWindow)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainWindow = mainWindow;

    // Other constructor stuff
  } 

  // Other methods, event handlers, etc.
}
```

Typically with dependency injection, we rely on abstractions rather than concrete implementations (to reduce coupling).

```
public interface IMainWindowThatDoesSomething
{
  void DoSomething();
}

public class MainWindow : Window, IMainWindowThatDoesSomething
{
  // Constructor, methods, event handlers, etc. go here.

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // Implementation here.
  } 
}

public class Page : Page
{    
  private IMainWindowThatDoesSomething mainWindow;

  public Page(IMainWindowThatDoesSomething mainWindow)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.mainWindow = mainWindow;

    // Other constructor jazz.
  }

  private void UserDidSomethingAndMainWindowNeedsToReact()
  {
    mainWindow.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well it doesn't sound right to do this, but if you have to get the object in memory rather than creating a new one..

but this dosent sound right .. tell us why u wanna do this so that we can suggest a better way

--- just to make your case work .. do this ..

In main window --

```
public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set; }

    static MainWindow()
{
    Instance = new MainWindow();
}

private MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

in app.xaml remove StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"

```
public App()
{
    Startup += App_Startup;        
}

void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    TestApp.MainWindow.Instance.Show();
}
```

and in Page now you have access to static Instance ... call method on that

Comment: I know, that is so wrong and it can't work. I am work on small program, I have method on MainWindow which can change grid background, but i must call that method from another page and i don't know how :(

Comment: whats the relation between page and mainwindow ?

Comment: my program have menu on left side, each item on this menu show another page in frame which is on the right side and each page show different things

Comment: if i call static method, so it works, but with static method i can't define xaml tools (i mean textbloc, label etc.) and their value :(

Comment: that's y we have design principles :)

Comment: no, i must define it in code behind because i want a dynamically change it, this do that method and its work, but i don't know how call it from another Page :/

Comment: okay, so, how can i define new tools on MainWindow if i click to the button on another Page? I need this way, i can't change whole program :(

Comment: I posted a patch commonly known as singleton.. use it and tell me if you have issues

Comment: I'm sorry, but the program does not start after I add your code :( and i must remove last line of code, it's same as first line... VS now write: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll_

Comment: I am try it, but "TestApp" is wrong word and i dnon't know what what there is to be :( sorry i am beginer

Comment: just write mainwindow and let intellisense find that for u :)

Comment: 'mainwindow' does not exist in the current context :D :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider leveraging messaging with parameters to pass around data between your objects.

You can use an [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/decoupled-event-management/).

The idea is to have your user controls subscribe to events that they would like to respond to.

NOTE:

I do this with viewmodels.
However, I think it is a code-smell when adding this code to user-controls that are meant to have general use regardless of the application employing them.

I use the ***Publish Subscribe pattern*** for complicated class-dependencies:

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CloseComand = new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    MessageBus.Instance.Publish(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, null);
                });
        }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    Subscription _subscription = new Subscription();

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });
    }
}
```

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to get the MessageBus.

**MessageBus**

```
public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton
    static MessageBus _messageBus = null;
    private MessageBus() { }

    public static MessageBus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_messageBus == null)
            {
                _messageBus = new MessageBus();
            }

            return _messageBus;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _oneTimeObservers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingSubscribers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingUnsubscribers = new List<Observer>();

    int _publishingCount = 0;
    #endregion

    public void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _observers);
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _oneTimeObservers);
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Respond == response).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public void Publish(string message, object payload)
    {
        _publishingCount++;

        Publish(_observers, message, payload);
        Publish(_oneTimeObservers, message, payload);
        Publish(_waitingSubscribers, message, payload);

        _oneTimeObservers.RemoveAll(o => o.Subscription == message);
        _waitingUnsubscribers.Clear();

        _publishingCount--;
    }

    private void Publish(List<Observer> observers, string message, object payload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var subscribers = observers.Where(o => o.Subscription.ToLower() == message.ToLower());

        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Respond(payload);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Observer> GetObservers(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        return observers;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _observers.Clear();
        _oneTimeObservers.Clear();
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response, List<Observer> observers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var observer = new Observer() { Subscription = message, Respond = response };

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }
        else
        {
            _waitingSubscribers.Add(observer);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

**Subscription**

```
public class Subscription
{
    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription);

        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            MessageBus.Instance.Unsubscribe(observer.Subscription, observer.Respond);
        }

        _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList().ForEach(o => _observerList.Remove(o));
    }

    public void Subscribe(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.Subscribe(subscription, response);
        _observerList.Add(new Observer() { Subscription = subscription, Respond = response });
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.SubscribeFirstPublication(subscription, response);
    }
}
```